# Type of distribution and mgf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

A tutoring class consists of 5 students and meets for a total of $11$ times. After each lesson, students take a quiz. The score of each of the $5$ students is equally likely to be $1,2,3, 4$ independently of other students.  Let $X$ be the sum of the quiz scores of the students in today’s lesson. What is the moment generating function of $X$?

I am very confused about what type of distribution $X$ follows. I figured I would assign a single distribution to each of the students, $X_k$, for the student $k$. Thus far, my guess is that $X$ follows a binomial distribution but the parameters are not clear. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: One approach for this specific situation is to consider each student's score to be the result of two coin flips.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor How would that work?

Answer (score 1):

One approach for this specific situation is to consider each student's score to be the result of two coin flips. So it is two sets of $5$ coin flips; the first set can be zero or one, the second set can be the "2's digit" and would add $2$ to the score if it is a $1$ and $0$ if it is a zero.

Suppose the first student gets a $1$. That would correspond to $X_1 = 0$ and $Y_1 = 0$ and the first score would be $2X_1 + Y_1 + 1$. If the second student got a $4$, that would correspond to $X_2 = 1$ and $Y_2 = 1$ for a score of $2X_2 + Y_2 + 1$.  The total score would be $\sum_{i = 1}^{5} \big(2X_{i} + Y_{i} + 1\big)$.

So you would have a sum of $5$ Bernoulli random variables (a binomial with $n=5$ and $p = 1/2$), and $2$x a sum of $5$ other Bernoulli random variables.
From there you can use theorems about moment generating functions.